# Data won't show when using datepicker as query param

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I want to set value of query params with a datepicker, but when I try it the data won't display. I have include ng-model into my query params but doesn't work.

Here is my `.js` file, I want to pass dt and dt2 into query params in http get

```
app.controller("repcont", ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
    $scope.dt2 = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyyMMdd'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };
        $scope.cari = function () {
        $http.get('......./rpt?a='+$scope.dt+'b='+$scope.dt2).then(function(response){
        $scope.report = response.data;
```

here is my .html file

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
            </p>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2" is-open="popup2.opened"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cari()"> Search  </button>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="jarak">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Tanggal</th>
            <th>Jumlah Bayar</th>
            <th>Jumlah Failed</th>
            <th>Jumlah Closed</th>
            <th>Jumlah Unflag</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="item in report">
                <tr>
                <td>{{item.paydate}}</td>
                <td>{{item.sumpaid}}</td>
                <td>{{item.sumfail}}</td>
                <td>{{item.sumclose}}</td>
                <td>{{item.sumflag}}</td>

            <p>Total Rows : {{report.length}}</p>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the result of my report:

[image]

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: nope, no errow @Zooly

Comment: what does the query string look like? are the values passed correctly? have you debugged?